# Exception thrown while enumerating list even while locking using syncroot

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, collections, thread-safety

Hey guys i have this following two classes. The start and stop method of the Foo class is called multiple times and some times the second foreach loop in the DoWork method throws the exception  "InvalidOperationException: Collection Was Modified". Since im using locking i don't know why this is happening.So please can some one point me to the right direction as to what i have done wrong.

Thanks

```
class Item 
{
}

class Foo
{
    private List<Item> items;
    private volatile bool bContinue = true;
    private object locker = new object();


    Foo()
    {
        items = new List<Item>();
    }
    public void Add (Item item)
    {
        lock (((ICollection)items).SyncRoot)
        {
            items.Add(item);
        }
    }

    public void Remove(Item item)
    {
        lock (((ICollection)items).SyncRoot)
        {
            items.Remove(item);
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        lock(locker)
        {
            bContinue = false;
        }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        Thread worker = new Thread(DoWork);
        worker.Start();
    }

    private void DoWork()
    {
        while (bContinue)
        {
            lock (((ICollection)items).SyncRoot)
            {

               items.ForEach((o) =>
                    {
                       //access memeber variables of o
                    }
                );

                foreach (Item it in items)
                {

                    //Call member methods of it
                }
            }

        }

        lock (locker)
        {
            bContinue = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: As a side note, `bContinue` should be declared `volatile`, otherwise the compiler is free to assume that the value will only be accessed by one thread at a time.  This may cause the compiler to optimize away the `while` condition in `DoWork()`, since you don't change `bContinue` from inside of it, and therefore the loop may never terminate.

Comment: Thanks i actually had 'bContinue' as volatile in the production code.But if i may ask your statement "since you don't change 'bContinue' from inside of it, and therefore the loop may never terminate" in what hypothetical situation can the loop not terminate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suspect that the "`//do some work`" code you have omitted is the problem.  Likely this code is modifying the `items` collection.

You cannot modify a collection while you are enumerating it, *not even from the same thread*.  This is a contract of the `IEnumerable` interface.

```
foreach (Item it in items)
{
    // The following line will cause an exception to be thrown on the next
    // loop iteration, because the iterator will detect that the collection
    // was modified.  You cannot modify a collection while enumerating it.
    items.Remove(it);
}
```

If you need to add or remove items from a collection while enumerating the contents of the collection, you must first make a copy of the collection and then enumerate the copy.  For example:

```
foreach (Item it in items.ToList())
{
    //do some work
}
```

`ToList()` will create a copy of the list, and you will then enumerate this copy.  Then you are free to modify the `items` list.

(Note that you do not need to do this if you are only modifying the `Item` objects themselves -- it's only required when changing the list by adding, removing, or inserting elements.)

Comment: @user119020 The case I mention is the only thing that can trigger the specific exception message that you pasted.  Follow every method call; the `items` list is being modified somewhere while it is being enumerated.  Better yet, run the program in a debugger.  The line the program stops on should be one of the foreach iterations; that will tell you which loop body you need to examine.

Comment: yea i will debug and see but ill have to wait till Monday for that.As you said `items` list have to be modified so im thinking may be i have done something wrong in the way im locking the list.Do you see anything wrong with the way i have used the locks is there a chance that Tread A accessing either `Add()` or `Remove()` while Thread B is in `foreach` loop of `DoWork()`?

Comment: @user119020 I don't see anything obviously wrong with the locks, no.

Comment: i think i may have found the problem.Inside the `foreach` loops i call callback methods.These methods calls `Add()` and `Remove()`. Since the call back methods are executed in the same Thread Context of `Foo` the lock becomes re-entrant and the synchronization seem to become violated.I guess i should use a better design than this

Comment: @user119020 CLR monitors (`lock`) are re-entrant.  The problem has *nothing whatsoever to do with locking*.  The problem is quite simply that you cannot modify a list while you are enumerating it.  You can do whatever kind of locking you desire, but **you cannot call your `Add()` or `Remove()` methods while you are enumerating `items`, *with or without any locking of any type***.